# Sequelize model.update with association

Tags: express, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to update BOTH the `hasOne` and `belongsTo` model through one call like the following (which works, by the way, with `create()`) where `user` is a returned instance:

```
user.update({
  email: req.body.email,
  Profile: {
    name: req.body.name,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    location: req.body.location,
    website: req.body.website,
  }
}).then(function(user) { //foo });
```

But for the life of me I can't get anything to work. I can easily call `user.Profile.update({})` and make changes to ONLY the profile model, as well as `user.update({})` but nesting will not work. Either the functionality doesn't exist, isn't documented well, or I need to update both separately using something akin to `async.waterfall`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for future reference, if anyone needs it. So far the only way I can figure out how to handle this is the use of `Promise.all()`. If any of the maintainers of Sequelize see this, I'd be super helpful to clarify/add the ability to update associated models at once.

Here's working code (where `user` is an instance from `User.findById()`:

```
Promise.all([
  user.Profile.update({
    name: req.body.name || '',
    gender: req.body.gender || '',
    location: req.body.location || '',
    website: req.body.website || ''
  }),
  user.update({
    email: req.body.email || '',
  })
]).then(function() {
  req.flash('success', { msg: 'Profile information updated.' });
  res.redirect('/account');
});
```